# flask database global variable

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

in my flask app I am using mongoDB and on the home page I have a form that is returning all the known collections in that particular database. I am asking the user to pick a collection they want to use as I will use that collection set to return all the documents in other routes or views.

Im struggling how to make this global "selected_collection" a global variable that all the routes and views can use.

for example on the index page I am able select a collection then on the submit it would redirect me to view db_selected there I was trying to make the selected_collection a global variable but if i got to the about view it get an error related to

I imagine I should use flask.g but im not sure how to get it to work. I have read some of the documents but they are a little vague to me.

```
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'selected_collection'
```

how can i make this work?

app.py file:

```
# INDEX
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    coll_name = get_db_collection()

    return render_template('index.html', coll_name=coll_name)


# LOGIN
@app.route('/db_selected', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def db_selected():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_collection = request.form['Item_4']
        selected_collection = g.selected_collection

        return render_template('db_selected.html', 
        selected_collection=selected_collection)


@app.route('/about')
def about():

    app.logger.info('selected_collection is {}'.format(g.selected_collection))

    return render_template('about.html')
```

index.html file:

```
{%extends 'layout.html'%}

{%block body%}
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to the index.html file !</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
    {% include 'db_query_bar.html' %}
</div>

{%endblock%}
```

db_query_bar.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url_for('db_selected') }}" name="Item_1" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Select DB</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Database Collection:</label>
    <select id="DB" class="form-control" name="Item_4" style="width: 70%" >
        <!-- <option value="">All</option> -->
        {% for item in coll_name %}
            <option value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer this for the global variable I ended up placing

```
app.selected_collection = "Some Value"
```

in the top of my flask code this will create a global variable I can use in all the views.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# CONFIG MONGO CONNECTION DETAILS
app.config['MONGO_HOST'] = 'DB-Host'
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'DB-Collection'

app.selected_collection = "Some Value"

# INIT MONGODB
mongo = PyMongo(app)
```